# Arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a structure names eye_record which has 6 fields, one of which is x_pos_measured_deg:[1800x1 double]

I want to declare an array in such a way that using for loop, i can get all values of that specific field into a new array and do some work on them. Can anyone show me how to do that? here is m code:

```
arr=zeros(1,1800); 

for t=1:length(eye_record); 
arr(t)= eye_record(t).x_pos_measured_deg; 

end
```

it gives me this error: In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same. How can i fix this? or how should i declare my array so that it won't give me this error? I want all the objects or values, which are in x_pos_measured_deg field to go into my new array.

Comment: Structures don't really have dimensions, they have fields. A structure isn't an array, they are completely different. Also, I guarantee the error doesn't say `A(i)=B`, I'm sure there is a lot more detail that you should look at! Finally, please come up with a [mcve], which will help you potentially solve your problem, but will also help people give you a better answer.

Comment: yes you're right. i'm sorry i wasn't clear. I'm new to matlab so i really don't the right terms, My question is this, When i try to debug it and keep my cursor above eye_record, it shows me 5 or 6 different fields, and i have to use the field x_pos_measured_deg:[1800x1 double]. but when i declare my array like arr=zeros(1,1800); and then try putting the values in that array using the for loop like this: for t=1:length(eye_record); 
arr(t)=temporal_window(t) = eye_record(t).x_pos_measured_deg;
it gives me this error:
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Comment: @matlabhater You really should edit your question with the detail that you put in this comment.  The question by itself, as was note by others, doesn't really make sense as it's written.

Comment: ok, how about now? or would it require some more detail?

Comment: *Please* read this [mcve] and give us some simple code that is runnable, or at least would run if the error you said didn't occur. Also, if you have a 1x10 array, and you set the 2nd element of it to be equal to a 1x10 array, what do you expect to happen? (That is hat you are doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `eye_record` is struct, not array, so you can not use indexing with `eye_record`. Your `eye_record.x_pos_measured_deg` is array and you have to loop through it. So the `loop` should be:

```
arr=zeros(1,1800);     
for t=1:length(eye_record.x_pos_measured_deg)
    arr(t)= eye_record.x_pos_measured_deg(t);    
end
```

But actually, you can assign values directly like:

```
arr=zeros(1,1800);
arr = eye_record.x_pos_measured_deg';
```

since you declared `arr` to have size of `1x1800`, and `eye_record.x_pos_measured_deg` has size of `1800x1`.

Without `arr=zeros(1,1800);`, then no `'` at the end:

```
arr = eye_record.x_pos_measured_deg;
```